# Firefox started to forget usernames

Tags: linux, firefox

I have Firefox 115.7.0esr (64-bit) on Linux. In some recent update (approx a few months ago) something changed.

Old behavior: User names were saved and I always opted to not save passwords. When I revisited any site I had the username available when I asked for suggestions (pressing down button while in the edit box).

New behavior: All user names were forgotten. No suggestion is available even when I ask for it. I have browsed the settings, I don't see any option that would reestablish the old behavior.

I would like Firefox to remember my user names, but don't remember my passwords. Searching the internet led to many near misses.

Comment: My Firefox is on version 122. Try to find this version, uninstall yours, and install version 122.

Comment: Did you perhaps disable form history?

Comment: @DanielB No, I haven't.

Comment: @harrymc The author probably has the Extended Support Release for a reason.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Yet he's still getting updates. The question is perhaps: Updates to what?

Comment: @harrymc What might you be referring to? Firefox ESR 115.7 is the current ESR release. It is fully supported by Mozilla. It has a well-documented update cycle.

Comment: @DanielB: The user is not saying which updates, Linux or Firefox. Also, if an update to Firefox loused up its installation, the immediate remedy is to uninstall and reinstall the new version from scratch.

Comment: @harrymc Company computer. I can't choose which version I use.

Comment: You could perhaps ask IT for help.

Comment: They would roll back or do something if there would be an issue with my browser that prevents me from working. But this issue is at mild annoyance level, they don't care, and they shouldn't. They have more important things on their plate.